# Is Visual Studio lacking of compile time check / intellisense on namespace in config files?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, namespaces, resharper, visual-studio-power-tools

I was dealing with Caste IOC container. The same operation can be done inside c# code and in the config file.

1. `ServicesContainer.InstanceForTest().Container.Register(Component.For<IUserDAO>().ImplementedBy<UserDAO>());`
2. `<component service="Services.Application.DAL*[...]*, Services.Application.DAL" type="Services.Application.DAL.User.UserDAO, Services.Application.DAL" />`

The first requires a reference and a compilation, the second one ***could*** be resolved also at run-time (but visual studio could try to check it also at compile time).

Actually there seems to be not suggestion or check by the IDE:

**IDE configuration:**

- Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate
- Resharper 8
- Web Essential
- Visual Studio Power Tool

**Can I enable some option to enable syntax highlighting?**

Comment: ReSharper usually catches those. Are you saying you can change the config to misspell the type, and there is no error displayed? Are you using solution-wide analysis?

Comment: @JohnSaunders: yes to both the questions.. maybe is there some other tool or resharper plugin?

Comment: No other tool or anything. In fact, ReSharper used to have a bug where it assumed anything in the config file with a "type" attribute was a CLR type, and it would complain when it didn't find the "type". Maybe they broke it while trying to fix that bug. Which version of R# are you using?

Comment: @JohnSaunders: this: Build 8.2.0.2160 on 2014-03-20T18:53:08

Comment: @JohnSaunders: how can I check for this resharper feature? do you remember the name?

Comment: I don't think it's a named feature. I just tried misspelling the name of an HttpModule, and it was immediately displayed in red.